# Reinstall OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am relatively new to Mac world. I've bought my first Apple computer, a MacBook Pro Retina 2013, a few weeks ago and I've tried a lot of software since then.

Anyway, to make a long story short, I have a problem with Xcode as descried in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992029/lldb-makes-xcode-5-1-crash-on-project-run) question I posted on stack overflow. I want to try reinstalling the OS to see if the problem will disappear.

About reinstalling the OS, my biggest concert is if all my files will remain after reinstallation. So, can you reinstall OS X without having to format your hard drive?

My mac came with Mavericks.

Comment: Did you try not using the CMD-R but something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify :-) Simply reinstalling an O/S (upgrading too) does not delete any personal files, it over writes only system files to a freshly installed state.

remember that the FIRST thing you do after re-installing is running software update and getting all the patches.

The SECOND would be booting from the recovery partition and repairing permissions and the disk with Disk Utility (in that order)

Comment: What exactly do I have to do in Disk Utility? It seems pretty serious. Can you provide more info?

Comment: @DragosRizescu you would use the disk utility to verify or repair the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your files first before installing the OS

Note: if you are upgarding from ex: mountain lion to mavericks you will not lose files.